# error setting user_root for devise redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

**Goal**
When user submits the devise "edit registration" form, I want to redirect to users#show rather than the site's root.

**Problem**
Following Devise's [instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile) has not worked.  I don't want to customize the Devise controller, so I'm left with two suggested modifications to routes.rb, either

```
devise_for :users do
  get 'users', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user_root
end
```

or

```
match 'user_root' => 'users#show'
```

The first redirects to http://localhost:3000/users after submitting the edit form, the second redirects to http://localhost:3000/user_root.  Both give the same error, "Couldn't find User without an ID".

My users#show page normally works in the app, so it's not an error with the controller method (or view, of course).  It seems to be a routing error.  I have "resources :users" in my routes.rb file, nothing else regarding users.  If I need to give more information please let me know!

**Question**
Why isn't the user id being passed in the url?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered making the action a member action? this will ensure that the url format is controller//action. I don't know if you can even use the member thing in the devise route definition, but that's where I'd start.

```
devise_for :users do
  member do
      get 'users', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user_root
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work.  I get a command line error when trying to start the server: "can't use member outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)".

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer. I should have tried this before suggesting it, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The member part doesn't work but if you take that out it is working for me. +1 to jaydel for close enough :P

```
devise_for :users do
  get 'users', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user_root
end
```

Another thing that I tried which also worked was :

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users' => 'users#show', :as => :user_root
  end
```